# После установки ubuntu не могу выбрать windows так как его просто нет в списке

Tags: windows, ubuntu

После установки Ubuntu в Grub нет Windows, есть только Windows Boot Manager.
Вот что пробовал:

```
sudo os-prober
/dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi

sudo update-grub

Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'

Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'

Generating grub configuration file ...

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-25-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-25-generic

Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic

Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-46-generic

Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings

done
```

Возможно как-то восстановить Windows?

Из Windows Boot Manager не восстанавливается и не запускается Windows

Comment: покажите вывод команды `lsblk`

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что вы поставили Ubuntu на место Windows, а boot manager остался. Т.е. стёрли винду, можете попробовать восстановить диск, чтобы вернуть нужные файлы

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. например, чуть подробнее (хотя бы ссылкой на подходящий вопрос здесь или описание в интернетах) описать процесс «попробовать восстановить диск».

Answer (score 0):

Сколько дисков и разделоа?
В любом случае, есть отличный тул Boot Repair, который нужно записать на флешку и загрузиться с нее. Есть режимы GUI и графический CLI, второй вроде получше работает. Тула демонстрирует установленые системы и автоматически фиксит grub.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair